Hotwater tank not working
I had a hot water tank installed and wired in for me, while they did that they added a switch also for the water pump to use.
Now the switch works and the pump works but the hot water tank doesn't.
I opened the fuse panel and I don't understand why only 1 wire is going to the 15amp that is labeled HWT.
Turning off that breaker does cut the power to the water pump.
I just feel like something is off I'll add images of my fuse panel.
Bad wiring? Shouldn't there be a white that also goes up?
But then why does the water pump work I'm stuck.


Edit Adding requested information and pictures
It's an all electric 120v mini tank, as in picture added, the metal line to the switch that's where the pump is plugged in and the switch and pump work.
I added a picture of what's behind the tank for wiring. All of this goes to the bottom 15a in the fuse panel. (House isn't connected to grid if that matters)



Can you add details on the hot water tank that you have and pictures of how it is wired? Unless it is a gas-powered tank, I don't expect it to do much on a single 15A phase.

that is the wrong panel, it is not for your water tank breaker, find the other panel, usually close to the electricity meter

Space Saver does show small 120V water heaters on their spec sheet (the actual model number of OP's heater appears not shown in their picture). This could be the panel driving the heater.

Please proofread your post afterwards. The panel label photo requires me to stand on my head to read. :)

The water heater's black power lead appears to run to the regular breaker at the bottom of the stack. This regular breaker does not need the neutral from the water heater to run to it, like the CAFCI breakers above require.
It is difficult to tell which white wire is which in the jumble in the breaker box. However, there are the correct number of white wires on the neutral bar: 1 for the main power neutral, 1 for the water heater, and the 2 from the CAFCI breakers.
Assuming you don't have a neutral wire dangling in the back of that jumble along with an unused neutral pigtail for another CAFCI in the neutral bar, it appears that everything is wired correctly.
One thing that should be pointed out:

I had a hot water tank installed and wired in for me, while they did that they....

If their work isn't working, they should come back and make it work. Hopefully you haven't finished paying them yet. Or maybe they'll be nice and troubleshoot it.
Confirm that the thermostat in the heater is turned on. If it is, then there could be a loose connection somewhere in the wiring in the breaker box or the heater wiring box.
One last item: That dangling fuse thingy at the switch box is disturbing. It doesn't look safe or up to code. See about replacing it with a UL-listed fusing arrangement, if it is actually needed.
